# React native expo Linking error: The navigation state parsed from the URL contains routes not present in the root navigator - whats wrong?

Tags: react-native, expo, deep-linking

App.js

```
const prefix = Linking.createURL("/");
export default function App() {
    const linking = {
        prefixes: [prefix],
        config: {
            initialRouteName: "Home",
            screens: {
                Home: {
                    path: "Home",
                },
                ChangePassword: "resetPassword/:email"
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
              <AuthProvider>
                  <Navigator linking={linking}/>
              </AuthProvider>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

```
import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()

export const navigate = (routeName, params) => {
    if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
        navigationRef.navigate(routeName, params);
    }
}

 <NavigationContainer onReady={onLayoutRootView} ref={navigationRef} linking={linking}>
      <MyStack />
</NavigationContainer>
```

```
const MyStack = () => {
   return (
     <Stack.Navigator>
     ...
      <Stack.Screen
                    name="ChangePassword"
                    component={ChangePasswordScreen}
                />
     ...
     </Stack.Navigator>
   )
}
```

when I click in the link (from my email)

```
exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/resetPassword/your@testemail.com
```

I get the error:

> The navigation state parsed from the URL contains routes not present
> in the root navigator.

When I dont add any linking but just click link : exp://127.0.0.1:19000/--/ChangePasswordScreen I dont get any errors. I need to include the linking as im trying to pass the param (email).

What am I doing wrong?